# Verify in app purchase receipt without external server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to verify an in-app purchase receipt by sending a JSON to buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt, but im not sure how. I can find lots of tutorials on how to do it with a php server, but I dont use an external server for my purchase. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are cases where validating receipts is an essential thing, but your case does not sound like one of those cases.  In your case, you are getting receipts directly from StoreKit and using them within the app.

The main reason someone would have to have validation of receipts is if they are 'delivering' content to an application from an external source.  In those cases, validating a receipt is essential because the receipt is coming from an untrusted source (the application could send any receipt it wanted to).

That being said, there is no reason you can't follow the exact process to validate local receipts as well (if desired).

Comment: I thought that a user with a Jailbroken phone could falsify a response from apple's servers to "trick" the app into thinking a purchase was made. Are you saying that's not actually true?

Comment: That is certainly possible, but if that user is that crafty, they will hack the hosts file and have it 'fake' the Apple validation too.  You can't really protect against all of those scenarios unless you include an external server in the process.